# SQL, PHP export to CSV

Tags: php, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have created this php script to pull some data from my database and export it to CSV.

I've got headers set to 0,1,2, but I need some static text in column 0.

Eg static, stock code, QTY.

The stock code, QTY are being pulled from the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code is below.

```
// open connection to mysql database
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

// fetch mysql table rows
$sql = "select ManufacturerPartNumber, (QuantityOnHand - QuantityOnSalesOrder) from iteminventory";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

$fp = fopen('inventory.csv', 'w');

     fputcsv($fp, array('0', '1', '2'));


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

?>

Comment: What do you mean by "static" in column 0? Some kind ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to put some kind of ID into the first column of your csv, so you have to add the "static" item in the first position of the array you'll get from sql result.

**EDIT - updated to have static value in the first column**

Example:

```
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    array_unshift($row, 0);
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$header = array('Static', 'Stock code', 'QTY');

$fp = fopen('inventory.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, $header);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
   $id = 0; // or whatever else you want to have in the first column
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
    array_unshift($row, $id);
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
    $id;
    }
```

Comment: If you want the same value in the first column for all of your rows (but I wonder why :-) ), there's no need for $i variable. I updated my answer...